# Call NancyFx action from another module

Tags: nancy

Is there a way to call a NancyFX action from within another module?

```
public class FirstModule : NancyModule
{
    public FirstModule()
    {

        Post["/FirstMethod/{id}"] = parameters =>
        {
            var response =  <Call second module and SecondMethod>;
            return View["blah"]
        }; 
    }
}
```

And then call a method on a second module:

```
public class SecondModule : NancyModule
{
    public SecondModule()
    {
        Post["SecondMethod/{id}"] = parameters =>
        {
            Do some stuff....
        };
    }
```

Comment: sounds like you'd want to push the implementation of "SecondMehod" into another object that both modules can take a dependency on and call into.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you need to call 1 module route from another, then you're design is wrong. Explain what you're trying to achieve and maybe we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Yes I agree it is bad design. The second nancy module is a restful service. The first is a website in a seperate dll and I would like to call the resful service api from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other commenters have noted, doing this seems like a design smell. Regardless ...

Change your code for the SecondModule as follows:

```
public class SecondModule : NancyModule
{
    public SecondModule()
    {
        Post["SecondMethod/{id}"] = SecondMethod;
    }

    public object SecondMethod(dynamic p)
    {
        //Do some stuff...
    }
```

and then in your first module, simply call the second module as needed:

```
Post["/FirstMethod/{id}"] = parameters =>
{
    var secondModule = new SecondModule(); //use dependency injection in real code 
    var response =  secondModule.SecondMethod(parameters);
    return View["blah"]
};
```

Of course, as @Christian mentioned, the best approach would be to move the common code out into a completely separate class and have both modules call to that instead.

Comment: Stinky design for sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for how to pass control from one action to another action in another module, and this was the closest I got to an actual answer. Just in case it helps someone else, here's the general case that I found.

The nice thing about this is that it allows multiple actions in multiple modules to be reached by the same url, but keeps things encapsulated in their most logical places.

In the source (the one to pass control) action:

```
public class IndexModule : BaseModule
{
    public IndexModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters =>
        {
            // Here we want to handoff to the default action in another module; this keeps the URL the same
            var itemController = new DbItemModule { Context = this.Context };
            parameters.itemId = 5; // Specific item to load in target
            return itemController.itemHomeSharedLogic(parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the target module:

```
public class DbItemModule : BaseModule
{
    public GeneralModule() : base("/item")
    {
        Get["/{itemId}"] = parameters => itemHomeSharedLogic(parameters);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is factored out of the /item/{itemId} route so it can be shared with IndexModule's default route.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameters">Object with (int)itemId property set for the item to show.</param>
    /// <returns>Value of the GET action handler for an item's homepage.</returns>
    ///
    public Negotiator itemHomeSharedLogic(dynamic parameters)
    {
        dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
        // ...set model properties...

        return View["db/item/index", model];

    } // itemHomeSharedLogic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is bad practice to design a Nancy application where one route needs to call another route directly.  However, I have a related, but different scenario.  I have an application where many of the routes represent items in a database.  These routes might take the form of `/{type}/{guidPrimaryKey}` or `/{type}/{humanReadableKey}` or even `/{type}/{humanReadableKey}/rev/{revision}`.  Consider a form where the user needs to tell the server which item in the database to use.  In addition to a search function, I would like the user to be able to paste in a URL representing the database item.  I don't want to have the code logic for all the different URL structures in multiple places, so it would be nice to take a URL passed in as a parameter to one route and get a response from the route it represents.  After a bit of hacking, I found a solution that works.

Create a class for calculating the response that takes dependencies on the core Nancy routing interfaces

```cs
public class UrlDispatcher
{
  private IRequestDispatcher _dispatcher;
  private INancyContextFactory _contextFactory;

  public UrlDispatcher(IRequestDispatcher dispatcher
    , INancyContextFactory contextFactory)
  {
    _dispatcher = dispatcher;
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
  }

  public async Task<Response> GetResponse(NancyContext context
    , string url, CancellationToken ct)
  {
    var request = new Request("GET", new Url(url), null
      , context.Request.Headers.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value));
    var ctx = _contextFactory.Create(request);
    return _dispatcher.Dispatch(ctx, ct);
  }
}
```

In your [bootstrapper class](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapper), instantiate and store
a copy of this utility class

```cs
public class Bootstrapper : Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.DefaultNancyAspNetBootstrapper
{
  private static UrlDispatcher _dispatcher;
  public static UrlDispatcher Dispatcher { get { return _dispatcher; } }

  protected override void ApplicationStartup(Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container
    , Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines)
  {
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    _dispatcher = container.Resolve<UrlDispatcher>();
  }
}
```

Then, from your module, the code would look like

```cs
public class FirstModule : NancyModule
{
  public FirstModule()
  {
    Post["/FirstMethod/{id}", true] = async (parameters, ct) =>
    {
      var response = await Bootstrapper.Dispatcher.GetResponse(this.Context
        , "http://test/SecondMethod/" + (string)parameters.id, ct);
      return View["blah"]
    }; 
  }
}
```